# Setting DI to new Controller and models in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm creating a RESTful API in Phalcon PHP, I set the DI and the database information as always using:

This is how I'm configuring the database in the DI.

```
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Postgresql as DbAdapter;
$di = new FactoryDefault();

$di['db'] = function() use ($config) {
return new DbAdapter(array(
            "host" => $config->database->host,
            "username" => $config->database->username,
            "password" => $config->database->password,
            "dbname" => $config->database->dbname,
            "schema" => $config->database->schema,
        ));
};
```

Then setting the DI

```
$app->setDi($di);
```

And I'm handling the actions like this:

```
//Gets a client information
$app->get('/client', array(new ClientController, 'getAction'));
```

The problem is that when ClientController creates a new model object it simply returns an error saying that the table was not found and I think is because it is not loading the database information from the DI, so my question is, how can I set up that information globally, is it not supposed that Phalcon do it?

The database works fine in the main application controller, but I want to order the methods in other different subcontrollers and there is where the database config doesn't work.

I'm doing this as stated in the documentation:

http://docs.phalconphp.com/es/latest/reference/micro.html

Thanks.

Comment: How are you configuring the `db` service in your config and DI?

Answer (score 0):

It might be to do with the fact that you pass an existing controller and Phalcon assumes you've set it up already, but I might be wrong… To find out, in your `getAction` check if the $di is set:

```
public function getAction()
{
    echo isset($this->di) ? 'di is set' : 'di is not set';
}
```

If it's not set, then you can manually set it before configuring the route:

```
$controller->setDI($app->di); 
$app->get('/client', array($controller, 'getAction'));
```

That would solve the problem if it's to do with the DI not being specified, though I doubt it :) Post more details about the actual error and how you're configuring your model if that doesn't work.